# Strange behaviour with ClassCastException at runtime

Tags: java, java-11, classcastexception

I am using Mapstruct to map convert one POJOs to another POJO model

Following is the method that mapstruct auto generated

```
        protected Map<String, GenericAttributeData> headerAttributeGenericDataTypeMapToStringGenericAttributeDataMap(Map<HeaderAttribute, GenericDataType> map) {
        if ( map == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        Map<String, GenericAttributeData> map1 = new HashMap<String, GenericAttributeData>( Math.max( (int) ( map.size() / .75f ) + 1, 16 ) );

        for ( java.util.Map.Entry<HeaderAttribute, GenericDataType> entry : map.entrySet() ) {
            String key = entry.getKey().name(); // THIS IS THE LINE WHERE I GET EXCEPTION
            GenericAttributeData value = genericDataTypeToGenericAttributeData( entry.getValue() );
            map1.put( key, value );
        }

        return map1;
    }

    protected GenericAttributeData genericDataTypeToGenericAttributeData(GenericDataType genericDataType) {
        if ( genericDataType == null ) {
            return null;
        }

        GenericAttributeData genericAttributeData = new GenericAttributeData();

        if ( genericDataType.getType() != null ) {
            genericAttributeData.setType( genericDataType.getType().name() );
        }
        genericAttributeData.setValue( genericDataType.getValue() );

        return genericAttributeData;
    }
```

This method basically takes Map of source POJOs and converts them to Map of destination models.
The build  is passing.

When I run the code, i am getting ClassCast exception in this method :***headerAttributeGenericDataTypeMapToStringGenericAttributeDataMap***

Stacktrace:

```
23 Jun 2022 09:34:46,218 ^[[1;31m[ERROR]^[[m dd6af157-4089-4b37-aa9b-225ed4b4394b (Bobcat-0) com.service.myActivity: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.service.dao.dynamodb.entity.header.HeaderAttribute (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.service.dao.dynamodb.entity.header.HeaderAttribute is in unnamed module of loader com.company.cloud9.launcher.BootstrapClassLoader @75bd9247)
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class com.service.dao.dynamodb.entity.header.HeaderAttribute (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.service.dao.dynamodb.entity.header.HeaderAttribute is in unnamed module of loader com.company.cloud9.launcher.BootstrapClassLoader @75bd9247)
        at com.service.adapters.mapper.InvoiceHeaderDoMapperImpl.headerAttributeGenericDataTypeMapToStringGenericAttributeDataMap(InvoiceHeaderDoMapperImpl.java:187) ~[myService-1.0.jar:?]
        at com.service.adapters.mapper.InvoiceHeaderDoMapperImpl.mapDOToInvoiceHeader(InvoiceHeaderDoMapperImpl.java:46) ~[myService-1.0.jar:?]
        at com.service.adapters.impl.InvoiceHeaderAdapterImpl.adaptDBInvoiceHeaderToCoralModel(InvoiceHeaderAdapterImpl.java:29) ~[myService-1.0.jar:?]
        at com.service.handler.SubmitAdditionalLinesHandler.buildInventoryInvoiceFromStagingDb(SubmitAdditionalLinesHandler.java:129) ~[myService-1.0.jar:?]
        at com.service.handler.SubmitAdditionalLinesHandler.handleAdditionalLineItemsSubmissionRequest(SubmitAdditionalLinesHandler.java:83) ~[myService-1.0.jar:?]
        at com.service.component.SubmitAdditionalLinesComponent.submitAdditionalLines(SubmitAdditionalLinesComponent.java:30) ~[myService-1.0.jar:?]
        at com.service.service.SubmitInvoiceActivity.submitAdditionalLines_aroundBody2(SubmitInvoiceActivity.java:84) ~[myService-1.0.jar:?]
        at com.service.service.SubmitInvoiceActivity$AjcClosure3.run(SubmitInvoiceActivity.java:1) ~[myService-1.0.jar:?]
        at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:167) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:?]
        at com.company.metrics.declarative.aspectj.JoinpointInvocationHandle.proceed(JoinpointInvocationHandle.java:60) ~[DeclarativeCoralMetricsAspectJ-2.2.jar:?]
        at com.company.metrics.declarative.AbstractMethodMetricInterceptor.handleInvocation(AbstractMethodMetricInterceptor.java:283) ~[DeclarativeCoralMetrics-2.2.jar:?]
        at com.company.metrics.declarative.aspectj.MetricMethodAspect$ConfiguredMethodAspect.invoke(MetricMethodAspect.java:108) ~[DeclarativeCoralMetricsAspectJ-2.2.jar:?]
        at com.company.metrics.declarative.aspectj.MetricMethodAspect.captureMethodMetrics(MetricMethodAspect.java:59) ~[DeclarativeCoralMetricsAspectJ-2.2.jar:?]
        at com.service.service.SubmitInvoiceActivity.submitAdditionalLines(SubmitInvoiceActivity.java:82) ~[myService-1.0.jar:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:?]
        at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[?:?]
        at com.company.coral.reflect.invoke.ReflectiveInvokerFactory$1.invoke(ReflectiveInvokerFactory.java:77) ~[CoralReflect-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coralx.exception.ExceptionTranslationInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:213) ~[companyCoralExceptionTranslation-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.reflect.invoke.InterceptedInvoker.invoke(InterceptedInvoker.java:74) ~[CoralReflect-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.validate.ValidationInterceptor.intercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:106) ~[CoralValidate-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.reflect.invoke.InterceptedInvoker.invoke(InterceptedInvoker.java:74) ~[CoralReflect-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.DefaultActivityInvoker.invoke(DefaultActivityInvoker.java:29) ~[CoralActivity-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.ContinuationActivityInvokerFactory$1.invoke(ContinuationActivityInvokerFactory.java:89) ~[CoralActivity-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.ActivityInterceptors.invoke(ActivityInterceptors.java:74) ~[CoralActivity-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.ActivityHandler.invoke(ActivityHandler.java:186) ~[CoralActivity-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.ActivityHandler.before(ActivityHandler.java:145) ~[CoralActivity-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.TransmutingContinuationHandler.before(TransmutingContinuationHandler.java:50) ~[CoralOrchestrator-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.Chain.componentBefore(Chain.java:94) ~[CoralOrchestrator-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.Chain.before(Chain.java:72) ~[CoralOrchestrator-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.helper.ChainHelper.before(ChainHelper.java:94) ~[CoralOrchestrator-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.AbstractOrchestrator.doWork(AbstractOrchestrator.java:84) ~[CoralOrchestrator-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.PassiveOrchestrator.enqueue(PassiveOrchestrator.java:93) ~[CoralOrchestrator-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.GracefulShutdownOrchestrator.enqueue(GracefulShutdownOrchestrator.java:301) ~[CoralOrchestrator-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.service.helper.OrchestratorHelper.enqueue(OrchestratorHelper.java:72) ~[CoralOrchestrator-1.1.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.bobcat.CoralServletRequestHandler.processRequestOrThrow(CoralServletRequestHandler.java:172) ~[Bobcat-3.0.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.bobcat.CoralServletRequestHandler.processRequest(CoralServletRequestHandler.java:150) ~[Bobcat-3.0.jar:?]
        at com.company.coral.bobcat.CoralServletRequestHandler.service(CoralServletRequestHandler.java:115) ~[Bobcat-3.0.jar:?]
```

I also tried to print the values of this method and they seem fine. I also tried adding debug breakpoints and the values seem okay.

Can someone please help here?

Comment: It looks like you have a string in your `Map<HeaderAttribute, GenericDataType> map` instead of a `HeaderAttribute` so when you call `entry.getKey()` it returns a String and tries to cast it as a HeaderAttribute. The problem is probably where you create the map.

Comment: I didn't understand. How can map of HeaderAttribute as key contain string as key?

Comment: I had a mistake in my example. Consider a raw type, `List objs = new ArrayList();` you can cast that to `List<Integer> ints = (List<Integer>)objs;` you can also cast it to `List<String> strings = (List<String>)objs;` so both instances will let you add Integer and String respectively. The problem will happen when you get an object from the list and it is cast. https://ideone.com/bjJREc that is a complete example. In your case, when you `entry.getKey().name();` there is an implicit cast to `HeaderAttribute` but your collection actually contains a string.

Comment: The data in  input to method is read from dynamoDb. Not sure how hashmap of enum would contain the string in the first placeI tried printing values of the i put and they all seem correct enum variable

Comment: " Not sure how hashmap of enum..." It depends on how you configured you object mapping. You have omitted the configuration. You need to create a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score -2):

It may be somehow connected with your aspects. Maybe some aspect replaces the value in your map, so it returns a value of a wrong type

Comment: This is a comment, and not an answer. Maybe you are right, and you can edit this into an answer by giving a specific example. Such as, create an instance where you get the ClassCastException.

Comment: the code provided by the topic starter does not give any information about the way the map is initialized and modified. Without it we can only guess what problems could appear and cause the problem. I don't see any reason to write here some abstract aspect code which could force change that state of the map and change it's content. As far as
```
 List<Integer> a=new ArrayList<>();
 List<String> b=(List<String>)a;
```  

would give you and error, there are two options. Either the topicstarter did use smth like 
```
Map a
```
(without generic types) or aspects did change the map

Comment: Why are you commenting about my otther comment here, it is confusing. It is better if you separate the two. What are "aspects"? Are you refering to the generic parameter? "I don't see any reason to write here..." exactly why you shouldn't answer the question until OP has clarified. I was just offering you a way you might make an answer out of your comment.

Comment: Aspects are a way of modifying code in runtime (and a special lib for that). 

 at org.aspectj.runtime.reflect.JoinPointImpl.proceed(JoinPointImpl.java:167) ~[aspectjweaver-1.9.6.jar:?]

here you can see that the topicstarter is using them. Aspects are modifying the bytecode during runtime and can make Map<String,Integer> take Boolean key as far as in Runtime Java does not know anything about generic types. I am pretty sure that this is what has happened in this particular case, but there are hundreds of ways aspects can be used so i can imagine how they are implemented in his code.